# How to find travel time

Tags: r5r

Im trying to find the travel time from centroids to each school location by R studio, these are the steps that I did:

```
library(r5r)
path <- system.file("C:/Users/JAVIER RUEDA/Documents/Proyecto access", package = "r5r")=
```

In the path I have only 3 documents: Centroid.csv, pbf file and SchoolsLoc.csv, but I have some issues in the next step:

```
r5r_core <- setup_r5(path, verbose = FALSE)
```

and the system give me the next error:

> Error in setup_r5(path) :
> Assertion on 'data_path' failed: Directory '' does not exist.

Please, someone help me to solve that, thanks

I try to solve the issue.

Comment: "*Assertion on 'data_path' failed: Directory '' does not exist*" - Are you sure you are actually passing a value for the directory? As we can see from the error message, it doesn't appear to be so

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the directory passed to `path` exists. It seems like you're passing an incorrect path as an argument.